# RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f doesn't work for .php files

Tags: php, apache, mod-rewrite

I have a symfony 2 website which requires all urls to be re-written to the document index.

Additionally, there are a number of completely independent "micro sites" which just run out of their own sub-folders in the web directory. I need to add re-write exceptions for any urls that point to the microsite sub folders

This is my .htaccess file:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/(microsite1|microsite2|microsite3)(.*)$
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ %{document_index} [QSA,L]
</IfModule>
```

This works for everything except .php files within the microsite folders, i.e:

- www.domain.com/microsite1/index.html ---works (displays index.html)
- www.domain.com/microsite2/            ---works (displays index.php)
- www.domain.com/microsite2/contact.php --- **doesn't work** (displays symfony route not found error)

aditionally:

- www.domain.com/microsite2/images/ ---successfully displays directory listing
- www.domain.com/microsite2/images/image.jpg --- successfully displays image

Comment: Turn on rewrite logging via the `RewriteLog` and `RewriteLogLevel` directives.  See what's happening.  Come back and post the log entries if they don't make sense or if `mod_rewrite` isn't doing what you expect.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You might need to change your apache config to something like this:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName server-name
    DocumentRoot /var/www/path/to/document/root
    <Location />
            RewriteEngine on
            RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
            RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
            RewriteRule !\.(js|ico|gif|jpg|png|css)$ /index.php
    </Location>
</VirtualHost>
```

Paying close attention to the last RewriteRule...

Answer (score 1):

Keep it simple - add this rule to your .htaccess:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/microsite1 [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/microsite2 [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/microsite3
RewriteRule ^.*$ - [NC,L]
```